# attr_accessible in Ruby on Rails 3 and its security implications

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been into rails recently and I am seeing this **MassAssignment Error** very often  in scenarios where I want to save the child with `parent_id`.

To fix this everyone are suggesting to add the associated foreign key to the `attr_accessbile` list.

I could resolve it by doing so but am not sure what happens under the hood. Is it true  that whitelisting the `foreign_key` would pose security problems?

Lets consider the following scenario of models:

```
class BusinessType < ActiveRecord ::Base
      has_one :business_form
      validates :name, :presence => true
      attr_accesible :name, :enabled  
end

class BusinessForm < ActiveRecord ::Base
      belongs_to :business_type
      validates :name, :presence => true
      validates_associated :business_type, :presence=>true
      attr_accessible :name, :enabled
end
```

In the above case whenever I try to save the `business_form` without `business_type_id` in `attr_accessible` list I would get mass assignment error. When I add it to the whitelist I am not getting any error message even the `business_type` select box is left empty and the form submitted.

I request anyone to shed some light in this area of rails. Please point me to any links that would explain in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it would pose security problems.  Say someone were able to make a post to your BusinessFormController#create and they passed the "business_type_id" as part of the post.  If your controller simply creates the record by doing something like this:

```
def create
  BusinessForm.create(params[:business_form])
end
```

then it is allowing the user to specify any business type for that form.  I don't know how your site works, but that might be a problem as certain users may be allowed to create certain types of forms.  The main concern with adding foreign keys to attr_accessible is that it's allowing hackers (anyone who knows web programming at all) to associate this newly created record with any of the foreign key objects.  If in this case you don't care or it's not restricted, then it may not matter.

If you still want to follow what people are telling you, why not keep the attr_accessible without "business_type_id" in it, but write your action like this:

```
def create
  bf = BusinessForm.new({:business_type_id => params[:business_form][:business_type_id]})
  bf.attributes=(params[:business_form].except(:business_type_id))
  bf.create
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Attr_accessible is very simple. You cannot assign a value sent from a web form unless that field is whitelisted by attr_accessible.

As for the security implications of mass assignment to a foreign key, you need to consider the following scenarios:

1. **It's acceptable for the foreign key to be set to any possible value.** There is no security threat from mass-assignment.
2. **The foreign key has to be one of a specific number of acceptable values.** In this case use a filter to ensure that the value passed from the form is acceptable, and reject it if it isn't.
3. **The foreign key will always be predictable value.** In this case, do not allow mass assignment and assign the foreign key using code.

Comment: what if anyone has changed the value of foreign key to a value that does'nt exist and sent them for submission.this would add records with invalid foreign key's

Comment: As long as you have the relation in your models then activerecord will throw an error saying the foreign key record doesn't exist.